# jquery.trigger("click") is called twice in google chrome

Tags: c#, javascript

the code:

```
 $(window).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.KeyCode == 13 || e.charCode == 13) { $("#<%=Send_btn.ClientID %>").trigger("click"); }
    });

    <asp:Button ID="Send_btn" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Send_msg_Click"></asp:Button>
```

c#:

```
 protected void Send_msg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     int ToClient = int.Parse(Request["frid"].ToString());
     int FromClient = int.Parse(Request["uid"].ToString());
     SendChatMessage(Message_txt.Text, ToClient, false);
     ConversationDIv.InnerHtml = GetChat(ToClient, FromClient, Session["history"].ToString());
     Message_txt.Focus();
     Message_txt.Text = "";
     var sc = "ScrollCoversationDiv('" + ToClient + "')";
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "MyScript", sc, true);
}
```

when i hit enter the Send_msg_click is called twice in google chrome why ?

Comment: Try with `keyup` instead of `keypress`. Tried on chrome, it doesn't trigger twice until you keep the key pressed. Moreover, if the button has focus and you hit enter, it will trigger twice.

Comment: Also since you don't have `e.preventDefault()` the original click is triggering the code, then you're doing `.trigger()` once that click happens, running the code again. Before the `if` statement, put `e.preventDefault();`